# Calling GetType on service interface causes invoke?

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, realproxy

I have a very basic interface for several services. Doing something like:

```
private static void Test(IService svc)
{
     var test = svc.GetType();
}
```

while passing in an instance of a remote service that inherits from IService causes the RealProxy Invoke method to be fired.

Why?

Comment: Why would it not - _"When the transparent proxy that is backed by the RealProxy is called, it delegates the calls to the Invoke method"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by stuartd this is expected behavior.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx